# How to share variable between init and doget?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets

In the servlet, I would like share a variable between init and doget

I am wondering if I should declare this variable using static or just normal

```
(static?) int small;

init()
{
    small = 5:    
}

doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
    small
}
```

Comment: Do you want `small` to be the shared among all users of the servlet? Or do you want an instance of `small` per request?

Comment: I would like to make sure I understand both cases

Comment: The servlet spec says that the `init` method is called before the first request. The same instance of the servlet is shared across all requests. It shouldn't make a difference if the variable is `static` or not unless you have the servlet declared multiple times in your web.xml

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter.  The Java Servlet spec will create a single instance of the servlet, and call init once.  Whether you put the value in a static or non static variable, it will be available to all threads executing doGet requests on that servlet.

I tend to use the static because it help make it clear to programmers that there is a single copy for all invocations, and a static is clearly not unique to a given request.  Also, a static is easier to access from other parts of the code (outside the servlet class itself) if you have any need for that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how better you want to design your code. I will suggest to go with non-static because think about extending this class by multiple subclasses.

Having it as member variable will allow you to have different values for different sub classes. Whereas, static you cannot.

```
public class Superclass {

protected static String sVariable = "static";
protected String mVariable = "static";

 public void init () {
 }


  public void print(){
  System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + ":sVariable" + sVariable);
  System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + ":mVariable" + mVariable);
  }
}

public class SubClass extends Superclass {

 public void init () {
  sVariable = "subClassSVariable";
  mVariable = "subClassMVariable";
 }


 public static void main(String a[]){
  Superclass superC = new Superclass();
  SubClass subC = new SubClass();

  superC.init();
  subC.init();

  superC.print();
  subC.print();
  }
}
```

The output of above code is:

```
com.ramesh.Superclass:sVariablesubClassSVariable
com.ramesh.Superclass:mVariablestatic
com.ramesh.SubClass:sVariablesubClassSVariable
com.ramesh.SubClass:mVariablesubClassMVariable
```